# mergZXing build issue

Tags: ios, iphone, livecode

Having an issue building for iOS. Getting "linking for arm (arm64) failed with Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "____libinfoptr_mergZXing", referenced from: -u command line option

Any ideas what might be wrong?  Let me know if you need additional details

Answer (score 0):

When you get linking errors with iOS externals it means it either hasn't been compiled for the SDK or architecture you are building against. In this case it's telling you it hasn't been compiled against arm64. The good news it that there are universal binary builds (armv7 arm64) available for download from mergExt.com for up to iOS 8.2. iOS 8.3 builds will be coming ASAP.

Comment: It is probably due to the fact I am not using the 64bit build of your external as my subscription has expired.  I guess it is time to re-subscribe to your services so I can the new builds!  

Thanks again for your response, Monte!

SKIP

Comment: I have gotten past this issue, obviously it had to do with the 64bit build.  Having said that, I have 7.0.5 and Xcode 6.3.1 and am building it out to my device which then crashes... here are some specifics from the device crash log:
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x2be62ea8
Triggered by Thread:  4